# What is the correct way to connect my package to GitHub after installing it via composer install

Tags: php, git, laravel, github, composer-php

I created a composer package inside the vendors folder in a Laravel installation.

I then created a GitHub repository and initialized a git instance in the package to version control my changes on GitHub.

Finally, I installed my package on the same Laravel installation via the composer. (I added my package name and version to the `composer.json` file and then executed `composer install`)

Now, on the same project, I want to be able to make more changes to the code and then add it to the repository.

I made the changes to my file. but then I did `git add .` I get the following error

```
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

I think when I installed the package, it deleted the .git file which is why I got this error.

Without screwing anything up, what is the best way I can connect my existing code to GitHub so I can push the new changes?

**UPDATED**

Here is the content of the config file located in /vedors/package/.git/config

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    symlinks = false
    ignorecase = true
    sshCommand = ssh -oHostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-dss
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://github.com/username/crud-builder.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    pushurl = git@github.com:username/crud-builder.git
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
[remote "composer"]
    url = https://github.com/username/crud-builder.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/composer/*
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - Delete your package folder in vendor

```
rm -rf vendor/yourname/yourpackagename
```

2 - Instal it again with sources

```
composer update --prefer-sources
```

The result of this is that `vendor/yourname/yourpackagename` will be a git repository in the end, and you should be able to commit and push again.

Comment: what does prefer-sources do? do I need to change my composer file so it knows which package I want to connect too?

Comment: You don't need to change anything else. It basically downloads packages using `git clone` instead of download.

Comment: so when i do `git push` I get I get the following error `Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.`

Comment: Check your /vendor/name/package/.git/config file. If you have a remote using SSH or git@, you can change to the https version and use your login and password to login

Comment: I am not really sure what I should be looking for in there. I updated my question with the content of my config file.

Comment: When I use the Git GUI instead of Git Bash, then go to `Remote >> Push` and then from I change the `Remote` option to `composer` instead of origin` then hit `Push` it seems to be working. I am not sure why I am not able to do this via the command line. Also, what is the different between composer and origin? Thanks for you help

Comment: In Git Bash it's working because it, probably, has access to your public and private keys. So, try changing `pushurl = git@github.com:username/crud-builder.git` to `pushurl = https://github.com/username/crud-builder.git`. But the best would be to create public and private ssh keys for this host you are now: https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent/

Comment: changing the value of pushurl worked. but I also tried following you suggesting by generating the ssh key. but sull getting the same error when using git@github... url